# How do I Format Cell Content that has been derived from a Formula in Java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create a Java POI application that iterates through a list of transactions that subtracts one value from another to produce a new value. In Excel this is achieved by subtracting the value of one cell from another and then writing the result to a third cell. The output looks like this:
[image: Fig 1]

The formula in the Net FC column represents a deduction of tax from a gross amount to produce a new amount (Net FC).  I have checked that this works by opening the Excel file and examining cell I.  It does what it is expected to do:
[image: Fig 2]

My issue is that I cant style the result consistently so that it shows as a column of correctly right aligned values, to two decimal places, like this:

[image: Fig 3]

I have tried so far:

```
private CellStyle getCellStyle(String fname, int size, boolean isbold, String align) {
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    switch(align) {
      case "L" : {style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT); break;}
      case "C" : {style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER); break;}
      case "R" : {style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT); break;}
    }
    style.setFont(getFont(fname, size, isbold));
    return style;
  }

 private void writeRows() {
    int row = 0;
    String font = "Cordia New";
    Dao.connect();
    TreeMap<Integer, Income> map = Dao.selectIncomesByYear("2023");
    Dao.disconnect();
    Income obj; 
    Iterator<Income> li = map.values().iterator();
    while (li.hasNext()) {
      obj = li.next();
      row++;
      XSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow(row);   

      XSSFCell cell = dataRow.createCell(0);
      cell.setCellStyle(getCellStyle(font, 13, false, "C"));
      cell.setCellValue(getPaymentDate(obj.getPymtDate()));  

      cell = dataRow.createCell(1);
      cell.setCellStyle(getCellStyle(font, 13, false, "L"));
      cell.setCellValue(getSecurityName(obj.getSecCode()));

      …
      
      cell = dataRow.createCell(7);
      String wtax = DecimalFormatter.formatAmount(obj.getWholdTax(), 2, '.');
      cell.setCellStyle(getCellStyle(font, 13, false, "R"));
      cell.setCellValue(wtax);
      
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator =    
            workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
      
      dataRow.createCell(8).setCellFormula(getFormula8(row + 1));
      dataRow.createCell(9).setCellFormula(getFormula9(row + 1));
    }
  }
```

The above code produces the first example of the Excel result shown above, that is without the formula cells being formatted correctly. As I am unable to proceed beyond this point I would appreciate some help in getting a solution so that the formula cells I and J contain right aligned values to two decimal places.

I  have found a solution from a 10 year old post, thanks Piyas De:

Create an instance of org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;

```
createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
```

Assign the value to the cell then use the helper to apply the format:

```
dataRow.createCell(8).setCellFormula(getFormula8(row + 1));
      cell = dataRow.getCell(8);
      CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("#####0.00"));
      cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that the cell style needs a data format as shown in [quick-guide.html#DataFormats](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats).

The formula `=G2-H2` results in a numeric cell value. Such numeric values ​​are automatically right-justified, but only display as many decimal places as necessary. To show 0 as additional decimal place a special number format (data format) must be set. This can be `0.00` or `#,##0.00` if thousands also shall be separated if necessary.

But there are other problems in your code.

You seems creating a separate cell style for each single cell. This is not recommended. Excel has [limited count of cell styles per workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). If that limit gets reached, cell styles will no longer be effective. Cell styles are stored at workbook level and are shared by all cells in all sheets of that workbook. Thus all needed cell styles need to be created at workbook level and then used while creating a cell.

Same is for fonts. Fonts also have limited count per workbook. So fonts also should be created at workbook level and then shared by cell styles.

Your code `String wtax = DecimalFormatter.formatAmount(obj.getWholdTax(), 2, '.');` converts the numeric value of whold tax into a formatted string. Then you set that string as the cell value. That's not recommended. Numeric values shall be numeric cell values too else calculations using those cells might fail. The green triangle on top left of your cells indicates this in Excel's GUI. So don't do this. Instead set the numeric (`double`) cell value and set a appropriate data format in cell style to proper format that value.

Following complete example shows how to do this more properly.

Used `Income` POJO:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Income {
  private LocalDate pymtDate;
  private String secCode;
  private double grossFC;
  private double wholdTax;
  
  public Income(LocalDate pymtDate, String secCode, double grossFC, double wholdTax) {
   this.pymtDate = pymtDate;
   this.secCode = secCode;
   this.grossFC = grossFC;
   this.wholdTax = wholdTax;
  }
  
  public LocalDate getPymtDate() {
   return this.pymtDate;
  }
  
  public String getSecCode() {
   return this.secCode;
  }
  
  public double getGrossFC() {
   return this.grossFC;
  }
  
  public double getWholdTax() {
   return this.wholdTax;
  }
}
```

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CreateExcel {
    
 private Workbook workbook;
 private String filePath;
 private Sheet sheet;
 private Map<String, CellStyle> cellStyles = new HashMap<String, CellStyle>();
 private Map<String, Font> fonts = new HashMap<String, Font>();
    
 public CreateExcel() {
  this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); this.filePath="./ExcelExample.xlsx";
  //this.workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); this.filePath="./ExcelExample.xls";
    
  // create all needed fonts and cell styles on workbook level
  createFonts("Cordia New", (short)13);
  createCellStyles();
  
  this.sheet = this.workbook.createSheet();
  
  writeHeaders();
  writeRows();

  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
   workbook.write(out);
   workbook.close();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();  
  }     
 }

 private void createFonts(String fontName, short height) {
  Font font = this.workbook.createFont();
  font.setFontName(fontName);
  font.setFontHeightInPoints(height);
  this.fonts.put("dataFont", font);
  Font fontBold = this.workbook.createFont();
  fontBold.setFontName(fontName);
  fontBold.setFontHeightInPoints(height);
  fontBold.setBold(true);
  this.fonts.put("headerFont", fontBold);  
 }
 
 private void createCellStyles() {
  CreationHelper creationHelper = this.workbook.getCreationHelper();
  
  CellStyle headerCellStyleLeft = workbook.createCellStyle();
  headerCellStyleLeft.setFont(this.fonts.get("headerFont"));
  headerCellStyleLeft.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
  this.cellStyles.put("headerCellStyleLeft", headerCellStyleLeft);
  
  CellStyle headerCellStyleCenter = workbook.createCellStyle();
  headerCellStyleCenter.setFont(this.fonts.get("headerFont"));
  headerCellStyleCenter.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  this.cellStyles.put("headerCellStyleCenter", headerCellStyleCenter);
  
  CellStyle headerCellStyleRight = workbook.createCellStyle();
  headerCellStyleRight.setFont(this.fonts.get("headerFont"));
  headerCellStyleRight.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
  this.cellStyles.put("headerCellStyleRight", headerCellStyleRight);
  
  CellStyle pymtDateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  pymtDateCellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd. MMM"));
  pymtDateCellStyle.setFont(this.fonts.get("dataFont"));
  pymtDateCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  this.cellStyles.put("pymtDateCellStyle", pymtDateCellStyle);
  
  CellStyle secCodeCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  secCodeCellStyle.setFont(this.fonts.get("dataFont"));
  this.cellStyles.put("secCodeCellStyle", secCodeCellStyle);
  
  CellStyle amountCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  amountCellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.00"));
  amountCellStyle.setFont(this.fonts.get("dataFont"));
  this.cellStyles.put("amountCellStyle", amountCellStyle);
     
 }
 
 private List<Income> getValues() {
  List<Income> values = new ArrayList<Income>();
  values.add(new Income(LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 3), "Three Chemes Fund", 72.0, 10.8));
  values.add(new Income(LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 10), "Stötafyg A B", 165.0, 24.75));
  values.add(new Income(LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 11), "Rising Damp Resorts", 4680.0, 702.0));
  values.add(new Income(LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 27), "Pang Technology", 43.52, 6.38));
  return values;
 }
 
 private void writeHeaders() {
  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  row = sheet.createRow(0);
  cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("Date");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("headerCellStyleCenter"));
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("From");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("headerCellStyleLeft"));
  cell = row.createCell(6);
  cell.setCellValue("Gross FC");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("headerCellStyleRight"));
  cell = row.createCell(7);
  cell.setCellValue("w/h tax");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("headerCellStyleRight"));
  cell = row.createCell(8);
  cell.setCellValue("Net FC");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("headerCellStyleRight"));
 }
 
 private void writeRows() {
  List<Income> values = getValues(); 
  int r = 1;
  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  for (Income income : values) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue(income.getPymtDate());
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("pymtDateCellStyle"));
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue(income.getSecCode());
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("secCodeCellStyle"));
   
   cell = row.createCell(6);
   cell.setCellValue(income.getGrossFC());
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("amountCellStyle"));
   cell = row.createCell(7);
   cell.setCellValue(income.getWholdTax());
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("amountCellStyle"));
   
   cell = row.createCell(8);
   cell.setCellFormula("G" + (r+1) + "-H" + (r+1));
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get("amountCellStyle"));
   
   r++;
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  CreateExcel app = new CreateExcel();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Axel for going through the code and making helpful comments which have certainly advanced my understanding of how things work in POI.